# git refuses to connect without proxy

Tags: git, proxy

I work on a Linux system in a Windows environment. To authenticate with a NT proxy server I had setup `cntlm` and configured system programs to use it via setting `http_proxy` environment variable in the `/etc/environment` file.

Now I want to remove this proxy setting and have the programs connect directly.

So I unset the system environment variables:

```
unset http_proxy
unset HTTP_PROXY
```

Check `~/.gitconfig` to ensure that there are no proxy entries.

Explicitly instruct `git` not to use any proxies:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Verify that no proxy is configured:

```
git config --system --get https.proxy 
git config --global --get https.proxy 
git config --system --get http.proxy 
git config --global --get http.proxy
```

And then push to a remote repo:

```
git push
```

But `git` still tries to connect via proxy:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx.git/': Failed
>   to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3128: Connection refused

Why won't it let go off `cntlm`?

Comment: did you check if there are any proxy set? `env|grep -i proxy`

Comment: @VocC Thanks VonC. I thought I had removed proxy by `unset http_proxy`. But there is a different environment variable for HTTPS which needs to be unset separately. Running `env|grep -i proxy` revealed that.

Comment: @VonC I have uninstalled cntlm from the system using `apt-get remove cntlm`. Do you know how I can debug why (and from where) the variable is being set now?

Comment: Do you mean the HTTP_PROXY keeps being set?

Comment: @VonC Yes. I have to manually unset every time I open a new terminal window. I've tried `rgrep https_proxy` in my home directory and `/etc` but can't find anything.

Comment: Did you check your .profile or .bashrc or other .xxx files?

Comment: @VonC Ah yes. I think that gets covered under `cd ~; rgrep https_proxy`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest check to do is:

```
env|grep -i proxy
```

The OP confirms:

> I thought I had removed `proxy` by unset `http_proxy`.
>   But there is a different environment variable for HTTPS which needs to be unset separately. Running `env|grep -i proxy` revealed that.

Answer (score 7):

1. use `cat ~/.` this will list all the files.
2. use `cat ~/.gitconfig` this will open the contents of file.
3. If you find any proxies there remove it like

   [http]
       proxy = http://127.0.0.1:3128
4. You can remove it by using `nano ~/.gitconfig` command.
5. Now this command will work.

   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

ALSO REMEMBER to remove all the proxies like

```
unset http_proxy="http_proxy"
unset https_proxy=$http_proxy
unset ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
unset rsync_proxy=$http_proxy
unset HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
unset HTTPS_PROXY=$http_proxy
unset FTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
unset RSYNC_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

Remember to remove proxies from system preferences network and proxies uncheck all the check boxes now try to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I ran

```bash
env| grep -i proxy
```

there was no output, so it seemed I didn't have any proxies.

Then I checked '~/.gitconfig':

```bash
[http]
        sslVerify = false
        postBuffer = 1048576000
        proxy = 192.168.0.xx:xxxx
[https]
        proxy = 192.168.0.xx:xxxx
```

I removed those two `proxy = ...` lines, then when running any git-remote related command, everything was fine.

Comment: Is this a new answer?

Comment: @Guildenstern I just shared my solution when I had a similar problem ;) And thanks Gino buddy for grammer check, my language is hopeless

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me. Just for temporary bypass this can be used :
**git clone --config http.proxy="" --config https.proxy="" your repository-url**