# Git Credentials issues with VSCODE

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Our company regularly forces us to change our passwords (which included the GIT repository).

So now when I try to push from VSCODE, I get the following error:

I followed what it said in:

[Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

and did a:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

I went into the control panel and manually updated the password. Then restarted VSCODE and tried to do a push again.

But I still get:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://ysg4206@bitbucket.draper.com/scm/pntci/orchestrator.git/': Failed to connect to localhost port 3128: Connection refused
```

I know I can get there, since if I put the url in my browser, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

That looks more like a connectivity issue, not an authentication (cached or not through a credential helper) issue.

As [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31021920/6309), make sure you don't have a proxy setup.
Or at least define an environment variable:

```
NO_PROXY=localhost,.draper.com
```

(assuming here you are contacting a server on a LAN, not on internet)

Comment: There is a gateway to internet proxy at the company level. I use a local http proxy to provide credentials for programs that don’t handle that. So https_proxy is set to that facade proxy. Http_proxy = Http://localhost:3128