# Git bash refuse connection on window

Tags: git, proxy, windows-10

I have read all the posts related to git including [StackOverFlow :  git refuses to connect without proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828237/git-refuses-to-connect-without-proxy)

I'm using git bash on Windows 10, recently when I tried to clone, push or pull my branches to a remote repository I get this message:
fatal: unable to access 'http://xxx/xxx.git/': Failed to connect to **192.168.1.4 port 8090**: Connection refused

that "192.168.1.4" is my local IP

I thinked I have set proxy on my windows and checked it by

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

and the result was

`"Direct Access (no proxy server)."`

So I instructed git not to use any proxies:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

and verify to not use proxy

```
git config --system --get https.proxy
git config --global --get https.proxy
git config --system --get http.proxy
git config --global --get http.proxy
```

And I noticed that no proxy is set on Windows or git
But my error is still there and I don't know why git wants to communicate with this IP(192.168.1.4) and (8090) to communicate with the remote.

[image]

Comment: How is your remote server name resolved? Can you do a ping on it?

Comment: yes I have ping to remote server. my remote server is local network and and I connect to remote by IP "http://192.168.1.172/git/nanotime.git"

Comment: Do you have any `insteadOf` rules in your global Git config? (`git config --global -l`)? Do you have anything cached in your credential manager? (`printf "host=192.168.1.172\nprotocol=http"|git credential-manager-core get`)

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry but I found what is the problem.
Not long ago, in order to be able to access a service on my system (192.168.1.4) from the Endroid emulator, I was testing different ways, and at the suggestion of someone on the Internet
I created the following variable in the system environment

> `http_proxy         192.168.1.4:8090`

I forgot to remove it